# Print text by string

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have this output in text file, from cassandra-cli. I need print `RowKey` and `OnlineUsers`, I'm using *bash*, and `grep` doesn't work.

```
Column Family assumptions read from /root/.cassandra/assumptions.json
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 1.2.19

Type 'help;' or '?' for help.
Type 'quit;' or 'exit;' to quit.

[default@unknown] use Agent;
Authenticated to keyspace: Agent
[default@Agent] list VCCs;
Using default limit of 100
Using default cell limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: cienciaactiva
=> (name=AllegroIntegration, value={"enabled":true}, timestamp=1504725823694867)
=> (name=CALL_licensed, value=1, timestamp=1504725823700706)
=> (name=CHAT_licensed, value=1, timestamp=1504725823695468)
=> (name=Id, value=cienciaactiva, timestamp=1504725823696915)
=> (name=IsSystemVCC, value=0, timestamp=1504725823699902)
=> (name=MAIL_licensed, value=1, timestamp=1504725823699520)
=> (name=OnlineUsers, value=1, timestamp=1504725823698413)
=> (name=WEBCONTACT_licensed, value=1, timestamp=1504725823697610)
-------------------
RowKey: atento
=> (name=CHAT_licensed, value=0, timestamp=1459855264796678)
=> (name=Id, value=atentoperusedapal, timestamp=1459855264801483)
=> (name=IsSystemVCC, value=1, timestamp=1459855264802006)
=> (name=MAIL_licensed, value=0, timestamp=1459855264797787)
=> (name=OnlineUsers, value=5, timestamp=1459855264796155)
=> (name=WEBCONTACT_licensed, value=0, timestamp=1459855264803923)
-------------------
RowKey: tsc
=> (name=CHAT_licensed, value=0, timestamp=1464217813009934)
=> (name=Id, value=tsc, timestamp=1464217813012789)
=> (name=IsSystemVCC, value=1, timestamp=1464217813016091)
=> (name=MAIL_licensed, value=1, timestamp=1464217813010988)
=> (name=OnlineUsers, value=7, timestamp=1485884014708000)
=> (name=WEBCONTACT_licensed, value=0, timestamp=1464217813012116)

3 Rows Returned.
Elapsed time: 178 msec(s).
[default@Agent]
```

The expected output would be something like:

```
RowKey: cienciaactiva
name=OnlineUsers, value=1
-------------------
RowKey: atento
name=OnlineUsers, value=5
-------------------
RowKey: tsc
name=OnlineUsers, value=7
```

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but probable because there's not attempt to solve the problem yourself: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **`awk`** command:

```
awk '/RowKey/; /name=OnlineUsers/{ 
        print substr($2, 2), substr($3, 1, length($3)-1); f=1 
     }f && /---/' file
```

The output:

```
RowKey: cienciaactiva
name=OnlineUsers, value=1
-------------------
RowKey: atento
name=OnlineUsers, value=5
-------------------
RowKey: tsc
name=OnlineUsers, value=7
```

Comment: @AlvaroMaravi, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

`grep` should be fine for this purpose:

```
$ grep -e '^RowKey:' -e name=OnlineUsers -e '^----' input
-------------------
RowKey: cienciaactiva
=> (name=OnlineUsers, value=1, timestamp=1504725823698413)
-------------------
RowKey: atento
=> (name=OnlineUsers, value=5, timestamp=1459855264796155)
-------------------
RowKey: tsc
=> (name=OnlineUsers, value=7, timestamp=1485884014708000)
```

If you need to remove timestamps from `OnlineUsers`, you can do this fairly easily with GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk -F '[(,]' '/^RowKey:/ || /^----/ { print } /name=OnlineUsers/ { print $2 "," $3 }' input
-------------------
RowKey: cienciaactiva
name=OnlineUsers, value=1
-------------------
RowKey: atento
name=OnlineUsers, value=5
-------------------
RowKey: tsc
name=OnlineUsers, value=7
```

Comment: @αғsнιη Sure, I've added an `awk` version that does that.

Comment: there should not be `-------------------` at first

Comment: The desired output can be achieved with just grep: the regexes need to be a bit more specific: `grep -oE -e '^-+' -e 'RowKey:.*' -e 'name=OnlineUsers, value=[[:digit:]]+'`